# Solving constrained least squares problem with modified linear constraint

Tags: optimization

could anybody give me some suggestions on solving this least-squares problem?

Find $x\in R^{n}$ that minimize $||Ax||_2$ subject to $||Bx||_2=1$, with $A\in R^{n×n} $ always full rank, $B\in R^{n×n}$ not necessary full rank.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is to minimize $f(x) = x^\top A^\top Ax$ s.t. $g(x) = x^\top B^\top Bx - 1 = 0$. Lagrange:
$$
A^\top\!Ax = \lambda\cdot B^\top\!Bx.
$$
$\lambda = 0$ would imply that $x=0$, which is not feasible. So, $\lambda\neq 0$. Hence, $(A^\top A)^{-1}B^\top Bx = \lambda^{-1}x$ so that $\lambda^{-1}$ must be an eigenvalue of $(A^\top A)^{-1}B^\top B$ and $x$ a corresponding eigenvector. From the constraint you also get that $\|Ax\|^2 = \lambda$. So, $\lambda>0$ and $\sqrt{\lambda}$ is the optimal value. Therefore, the minimizers of this problem are the eigenvectors $x$ of $(A^\top A)^{-1}B^\top B$ with $\|Bx\|=1$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $(A^\top A)^{-1}B^\top B$.

By the way, this is not really a least squares problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wonder that do you consider when B is not full rank?

Comment: I assumed this throughout.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you for suggestion

Comment: I doubt that the answer is correct. The Lagange (derivative in x) is not what you wrote

Comment: It must be $Ax + x^TA =\lambda( Bx +x^TB)$

Comment: @NN2 $Ax + x^TA$ doesn't even make sense.

Comment: This kind of problem is quite new to me. Could anyone please explain a bit more on the Lagrange method for this problem. Where the equation comes from?

Comment: @EdenWilly Lagrange says: If $x^*$ is a minimizer of $\min f(x)$ s.t. $g(x)=0$, then there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that $\nabla f(x^*) = \lambda\cdot\nabla g(x^*)$.

Comment: You dont write corectly the derivative!

Comment: oh I see, @NN2 is correct for the derivative term. $d/dx(x^TAx)=(A+A^T)x$

Comment: @NN2 Yes, I did because I don't differentiate $x^TAx$ but $x^TA^TAx$ and its derivative is $2A^TAx$.

Comment: Ok I see now. .

Comment: @NN2 Well, then you can upvote my answer again.

Comment: Sorry, the answer is locked by the system so I can’t modify that (unless you modify something in your answer)

Comment: @amsmath, hi, I have a question, the minimizer of this problem is the eigenvector corresponding to the largest or smallest eigenvalue?

Comment: @EdenWilly I wrote it: largest. If you understand my answer, then you'll understand why.

Comment: @amsmath Oh ok, I got it. Thanks

Comment: @amsmath Hi, i have a problem when solving this, could you please explain a bit. I try to find the eigenvector corresponding to largest eigenvalue of $(A^TA)^{-1}B^TB$ as the x vector. However, the result cannot satisfy the constraint. How should I solve this? Many thanks

Comment: In my answer I write "the eigenvectors $x$ of $(A^TA)^{-1}B^TB$ with $\|Bx\|=1$." If you have found an eigenvector $u$, then $x=\|Bu\|^{-1}u$ is your minimizer.

Comment: Hi @amsmath, I have tried your suggestion but it's still the same, the vector $x$ is equal to $u$.

Comment: If $x=u$, then $\|Bu\|^{-1}u = u$, which implies $\|Bu\|=1$, so $u$ already satisfied the constraint before.

Comment: @amsmath Hi, thank you for your support, I can solve this problem now.